# how to sed replace whole line with the string as variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

how to sed replace whole line with the string as variable ?

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh $1 ssh-keyscan -t rsa $1 > /tmp/$1
RSA=$(cat /tmp/$1)
echo $RSA
sed -i 's:'^"$1".*':'"$RSA"':' /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
cat /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts | grep $1
```

It is storing the variable in RSA but not replacing, not sure what's wrong with sed part.

Comment: Can you show us with some values and how do you claim it is not replacing?

Comment: $1 is the hostname of the remove node, when I do cat the file, it has the same old rsa key entry.

Comment: What is the value of $1?

Comment: need something like if exists replace or add it as new

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following command.

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh $1 ssh-keyscan -t rsa $1 > /tmp/$1
RSA=$(cat /tmp/$1)
echo $RSA
sed -i -e "/$1/ d" -e "/^$1/ a $RSA" /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
cat /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts | grep $1
```

I modified as per your requirement to add if not line exists and replace if it exists.

Comment: sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unterminated `s' command

there are white space and / there in the RSA token string

Comment: need something like if exists replace or add it as new

Comment: Then you might need to perform two commands.
`sed -i -e "/$i/ d " -e "/^$1/ c $RSA" /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`

Comment: Basically we are removing what we are searching and add new line.